# Vertical alignment of inline element in table-cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have multiple divs with dynamic content and all of them have the same height. Beside the content a Submit Button is inside of each div, which is directly next to the content. 
But i want to display the Button at the bottom of the div.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="product-teaser-row">
    <div class="product-teaser">
         <h2>Title</h2>

        <p>Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content</p>
        <button class="btn btn-grey" type="submit" name="action">Ansehen</button>
    </div>
    <div class="product-teaser">
         <h2>Title 2</h2>

        <p>Content</p>
        <button class="btn btn-grey" type="submit" name="action">Ansehen</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
div.product-teaser {
    border: 1px #c7d2d6 solid;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 216px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

div.product-teaser-row {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

I've already tried different things like `vertical-align: bottom` on the div and `display: inline-block` on the Button, but nothing worked for me.

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cr4zM/) of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you just have to **position** `absolute` your button and define the bottom position and give a `padding-bottom` to your container to be sure that no content will override your button.

here for a [jsfiddle exemple.](http://jsfiddle.net/LVWtF/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHzji)

CSS

```
div.product-teaser {
    border: 1px #c7d2d6 solid;
    padding: 0px 10px 20px 10px; /*Increase the bottom padding so the button does not overlap the content*/
    width: 216px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
  position: relative; /*Add this css*/
}

/*Set the button at the bottom using position: absolute;*/
    .btn-grey {
      bottom: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `height` property to the `p` element.

**Example:**

```
p{
  height: 95px;
}
```

JSFiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/g3p2Y/1/

Comment: Didn't worked, because i need in a dynamic height in `p` Tag. Also tried with `height: 100%;` but had also no success.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put `button` in separate `<div>` tag like:

```
 <div id=my>

     <button class="btn btn-grey" type="submit" name="action">
           Ansehen    
     </button>

</div>
```

set according `margin-top` to put the button at bottom like:

```
#my
{
   margin-top:100px;

}
```

[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/cr4zM/4/)